# docker-compose up error executable file not found in $PATH trying to learn about docker

Tags: docker

i am following the "get started" exercise her: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

as soon as i try `docker-compose up`

I get this output:

```
dings@me:/home/composetest$ sudo docker-compose up
Recreating composetest_web_1 ... 
Recreating composetest_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for composetest_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"flask\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"flask\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I tried: turn off my vpn

move the whole directory directly to the home folder

I searched all files for spelling errors

i don't know what to do about $PATH

did anyone encounter this and could help me please?

thank you!

Comment: There is nothing related to vpn. The error is talking about missing binary in the container. which container are you running ?

Comment: According to the documentation you pointed, it asks you to build a flask server and to copy it during build time. did you do so?

Comment: Useful answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734396/docker-container-build-faild-exec-flask-executable-file-not-found-in-pa