# Docker container build faild: "exec: \"flask\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker. I try run a sample dockerfile on docker,com. But I have a problem is "Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"flask\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
".

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask","run"]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have `flask` in requirements.txt? Please wrap your Dockerfile in a code block so it is easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, I checked  the requirements.txt. I have two line:  flask and 
redis. I follow this : https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Comment: Could you update commands you used with docker for your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `flask` is not found from the PATH. It is either not installed (is it in requirements.txt?), or just not added into path.

You could try to set `CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run"]` instead.

Edit: Example here works for me well. https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

You could try to pass `--no-cache` option to just in case make clean image: `docker build --no-cache -t test .` and then run `docker run test`

When attempting to test image, before going into `docker-compose` state.

Comment: I checked the requiremets.txt, I has two line flask and redis. I'm following this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted. I tried your way. It still error. Many thank s for help me.

Comment: I updated answer with examples, how it worked for me.

Comment: I ran "docker-compose up", It isn't working. I tried run "docker build". It's working.

Comment: Did you try ”docker run” as well?

Comment: Yes,  ”docker run” as well. It's working now. I set CMD is CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run"] and remove old container and image those are created by "compose up" before that. Thank you so much.